# Combining two words to make another

Tags: word, wordplay

[image: Here is the source of the puzzle]
(Source from this password-protected link: https://dumpz.org/adwGpTs3Mg5B)

Here are two examples of correct answers:

To lose one's CD ---> To make known
ANSWER: Disc-lose  Disclose

Who's great deed? Oh, hers ---> Down
ANSWER: Feat-hers  Feathers

Now, what are the answers to these?

When road vehicles turn bad ---> Delicious

The sounds of precious rocks ---> Jewelry

Comment: What exactly is this from? Is this from a competition of some sort?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

When road vehicles turn bad ---> Delicious

> Car + rot is Carrot